# Reading/Writing PDF Files in Visual C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

For a client, I need to be able to read and write PDF files. There are two downsides to this:

1. I don't know how.
2. I can't use any third-party copmonents/libraries.

Can somebody please point me into the right direction where I might be able to learn how to begin reading and writing PDF files?

I'm not asking for code or anything like that (although..... ;)), I'm just wondering if anybody knows of any good starting points...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PDF format is actually standardized in the form of [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502).  You can always purchase it from the website and implement a reader/writer/renderer yourself.

However, I'd *strongly* recommend against that, as the cost of the document and the cost in time of actually implementing something like this on your own will *far* outweigh the cost of a third-party component.

There are plenty of [third-party components for .NET](http://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+.net), some that (with [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) being a very prominent one) are royalty-free as well.

I'd suggest convincing whomever set the requirement that you can't use third-party components to sign-off on the expenditure of one of these components (if none of the free ones do what you need).

Comment: Thank you for this. So, if they are free, or royalty free, that means that we can sell them to our client, and they can be used commercially?

Comment: @j-t-s: Yes, if something is open-source, then *typically* the only thing you are obligated to do is attribute the source (indicate somewhere in the program that you use the component). **Make sure to read the license to see what the requirements are**. For most commerical options, they usually have a royalty-free condition, meaning you don't owe them anything for using the component in the application. Again, **make sure you look over the license**, but typically, "royalty-free" is what you want to look for.

Comment: @casperOne - Just to clarify "sell them to our client" - basically you sell *your product*, it simply uses open source libraries - you don't in effect "charge" for the library. Oh, BTW, check out ItextSharp.  PK :-)

Comment: @Paul Kohler: Yes, that's how I understood it, I think you meant that comment to j-t-s.  The link to iTextSharp is in the response, but I've named it specifically now.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers stated writing your own PDF handler will be a pain. You can try using [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) which seems promising and is free. You have to check the license of usage thou.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the answers above. Implementing a PDF engine isn't a trivial task. If you need to do the full one reading and modifying PDF, then use third party library like suggested.

I have worked with PDF document creation, management and etc for several years. Often I found that the requirement to handle PDF can be very basic and achieved quite easily but misunderstood.  I will just list some options here to consider if one of your requirement fall in to this category:

- For displaying PDF within you program, you can drop a browser control and setting the Navigate URL to the pdf document will automatically display the inline PDF just like in the IE browser.
- If you need to produce from an existing document, you can simply use print driver like doPDF, PDFCreator and etc and automate the process of printing to the driver
- If you are creating the document from Word, you can automated Word2007 and use the SaveAsPDF interface offered
- If you need to transform it to different format, depending on the target format Ghostscript commands are worth checking out too.