# Programmatic Reading of PDFs in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I see many questions and answers about using C# to generate PDF files.
 I have a related, but different task.

I have a large number of PDF files already created, and I would like to validate certain parts of the content with Regular Expressions (RegExs).  I want to open the PDFs in C#, and be able to read out the text in something approaching a linear fashion.

If headers, footers, any sidebars, etc, get skipped or read out of order, it doesn't matter.  I'm just after as much of the main-body text as I can retrieve.

Can you point me towards tools, libraries, API's, etc, that will enable me to programmatically read text in PDF files?

Comment: Thanks for all the wonderful answers.
I will be attempting these packages soon, and hopefull accept a "best answer" shortly after that.

Comment: Labeled as Not Constructive - but it sure helped me understand what is available!  If it's not a good fit for Q&A format - where should this type of question be posted?

Comment: I recommend that this be migrated to Software Recommendations.  This is exactly the case for that site.  This is a wonderful question that is and has been very helpful to lots of people, but it doesn't quite fit the format of SO.

Comment: When this question was asked, 4 years ago, I don't think Software Recommendations even existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used [PDFSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/) not later than last automn and found it very easy to use in comparison to others. Home page for [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used two different libraries for this purpose. One is [PDF Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) (part of the Apache project), and also one from [Snowtide Informatics](http://www.snowtide.com/).

Both are Java libraries, but you can use then with .NET in combination with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: PDFxStream (née PDFTextStream) is also distributed as a .NET assembly (courtesy of IKVM as Nick mentions, though the distribution is precompiled to .DLLs, avoiding the runtime interpretation->compilation step when IKVM is used to consume Java libraries as-is).

Answer (score 2):

There is a library for .NET called
[PDF Clown](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/)

There is also a nice article over at codeProject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx)
that details a few other libraries and approaches for reading
PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

Comment: @Joe: you'll get more upvotes if you do more than just post links.

Comment: the question is about reading pdf content, not generating.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) was a popular answer [Reading PDF documents in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83152/reading-pdf-documents-in-net)

Also check out [Reading/Writing PDF files in Visual C# Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301158/reading-writing-pdf-files-in-visual-c-windows-forms)